# Should "img alt text" be populated in multiple languages

Tags: html, wordpress, tags, alt

I have a WordPress portfolio website whose target area is Holland, but it is set up in English because I don't want to limit the audience to Dutch speakers. I would like to populate the img alt text in English and Dutch since I like my site be found with Dutch Key words too. Will my rankings suffer if I do that?

Comment: according to John Mueler (google employee) : "Alt attributes are essentially to tell users what an image is about, so if you have the rest of your content localized, it would make sense to localize those too."

Answer (score 4):

I strongly recommend reading [Use of ALT texts in IMGs](https://web.archive.org/web/20180311182502/http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html).

The alt attribute is supposed to contain a plain text **replacement** for the image for use if the image cannot be displayed (or if the user is using assistive technology such as a screen reader).

If you replace the images with a mix of English and Dutch in a document that is otherwise entirely written in English, then it wouldn't make sense. So don't do that.

The purpose of alt text is **not** to stuff keywords for search engines.

Comment: @t3__rry — Link updated. The body of the answer does cover the key points though.